# Collada model causes A-Frame to crash when panning around

Tags: three.js, aframe

I've loaded a Collada .dae model into my A-Frame scene and animated the camera movement around it then use the mouse cursor to orient the camera using universal-controls from the aframe-extras component. About 50% of the time it is fine, but the other times it throws a error:

```
aframe.js:30870 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
  raycast           @   aframe.js:30870
  intersectObject   @   aframe.js:16216
  intersectObject   @   aframe.js:16224
```

from the line:

```
if ( uvs ) {
    var uvs_f = uvs[ f ];
    uvA.copy( uvs_f[ 0 ] );// <- that's where this error came from
    uvB.copy( uvs_f[ 1 ] );
    uvC.copy( uvs_f[ 2 ] );
    intersection.uvIntersection( intersectionPoint, fvA, fvB, fvC, uvA, uvB, uvC );
}
```

It looks very similar to the question here: [Three.js drag the object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39545730/three-js-drag-the-object) (but it unfortunately does not have an answer)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there's an issue wherever it's intersection. I think we might have to PR to A-Frame's cursor to catch such errors.

Comment: thanks, Iv'e surrounded the intersection block with a try catch and that's allows it to carry on, but a bit of a hacky fix.